# PHP possible bug with max_input_time?

Tags: php, command-line-interface

According to [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-time), `max_input_time` is just supposed to give PHP time to parse GET/POST variables, and has no effect once script execution begins.

> max_input_time integer This sets the maximum time in seconds a script
>   is allowed to parse input data, like POST and GET. Timing begins at
>   the moment PHP is invoked at the server and ends when execution
>   begins.

```
root@server [/]# php -d max_execution_time=0 -d max_input_time=2 -r '$i=1;while($i > 0) { $i++; }'

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 2 seconds exceeded in Command line code on line 1

Call Stack:
    0.2004     228000   1. {main}() Command line code:0

root@server [/]#
```

Setting the maximum execution time to 0 should cause there to be no limit, and indeed if you remove the `max_input_time` directive then the script keeps running. But if you set `max_input_time=2` then you get the above result.

Is this a bug? And if not, how do you explain this behavior? Is the command line PHP considered to be "input data"?

PHP 5.5.20 on CentOS 6.

Comment: I think maybe you confuse it with max_time_limit; why are you running an infinite loop anyway. - nevermind, about that, isn't -r  input? for the command line>?  Who knows, just make sure to use /dev/null 1 &2 on your cron jobs on CentOS 6 because the buffer stops at 2mb, just saying :)

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix Running infinite loop just to isolate what I think is the problem. In my cron I am calling a script and using `-d max_execution_time=0` and yet it is failing with `Maximum execution time of 0 seconds exceeded`. So I ran this infinite loop on the command line to see if `max_input_time` could be the problem. I don't know if it is yet, but if the script completes when it runs tomorrow morning, then I will know it was.